# How to delete a file reading the path from file using shell

Tags: shell

I want to delete some java files in a directory from reading the path  from the file and i am getting the path of the file but my if condition is not able to delete the file .Please help me to resolve how i can delete the file.  the code i have used is as below

```
grepresult=`grep "Cannot Handle File" input.txt | cut -f 2,3 -d":"`

file1=`echo "${grepresult//\\/\\\\}"`

if [ `echo "$grepresult"|grep -ci ".java"` -gt 0 ]
then
    rm -rf $grepresult
    sh ./PSE.sh $1 $2
else
    echo "\$grepresult is empty"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add double quotes in your test :

```
if [ "`echo "$grepresult"|grep -ci ".java"` -gt 0" ]
```

Comment: This works on my machine (`bash --posix`). Which shell do you use ?